# Use the_post_thumbnail as background image in LESS CSS

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to use `the_post_thumbnail` featured image as the background image to a div container within a page template file.

I'm using LESS CSS and wondered if it was possible to pass in a Wordpress tag to the LESS file or use PHP in anyway?

If not, I guess my only option would be inline style?

Comment: To use a PHP function in a stylesheet you have to create the stylesheet with PHP-- for example, WordPress does this with `load-styles.php` on the backend--, or configure your server to process `.css` files as if they were PHP. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136331/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-php-to-less At any rate, this doesn't look WordPress specific to me.

Comment: Posted it here incase someone was able to come up with a Wordpress specific way of using featured image as background image in CSS. Thanks.

Comment: WordPress can't escape the basic rules of PHP, HTML/CSS, and HTTP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with an inline style in this case - just set all your other rules in your LESS (like background position, repeat, size), and then in your template:

```
<div class="something"<?php

if ( $id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
    if ( $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id ) )
        printf( ' style="background-image: url(%s);"', $src );
}

?>>
```